# ListView: elements not shown? c#

Tags: c#, listview, listviewitem

I have two forms using a `ListView` component. In the first form it works perfectly (all items are printed in the `ListView`), while in the second (which has the same structure) no, the `ListView` stays blank.

What I'm doing wrong? 
`lista` is a list.

The number of elements = `longitud`, which is defined in the main function.

There is the code:

```
public void llenarTabla()
{
    int idx;
    string tmp;
    string elemento;

    for (idx = 0; idx < longitud; idx++)
    {
        tmp = Convert.ToString(idx + 1);
        ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(tmp);
        elemento = Convert.ToString(lista[idx]);
        lvi.SubItems.Add(elemento);
        listView1.Items.Add(lvi);
        listView1.View = View.Details;
        listView1.Refresh();
    }

}
```

- I also tried to see if the list has any elements (as it is supposed to be):

  ```
  for (int idx = 0; idx < longitud; idx++) // test
      Console.WriteLine(lista[idx]);
  ```

and in the "output window" it prints some elements.

- I also tried to put `.View = ...` and `.Refresh()` outside the cycle. But same result.

Thank you for any help

Comment: Where are you filling or loading the second listview..??

Comment: If it works on form1 and not on form2, then you should concentrate on what's different regarding to your listview between those 2 forms. Also post the code that instantiates the listviews.

Comment: The code is exactly what I posted. I meant.. I have one form with ONE listview , and one form with ONE listview . The problem is I looked and there is just one difference.. in the form where the listview works correctly lvi.SubItems.Add(elemento);  uses an array of elemento (elemento[]) but even creating a elemento[1] the problem is the same

Comment: @dragonmnl What about the code that **actually instantiates** the listviews? It's probably located in a `Form1.designer.cs` file. Search for `listView1 = new ListView()`

Comment: @Ken2k The code is:                                       this.listView1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ListView();                    and the columns are defined in designer

Comment: @dragonmnl You should post the whole piece of code that initializes all the properties (and columns) of both of your listviews.

Comment: I can't..I don't have enough reputation :( Any idea how to solve the problem? (I can send you the code by private message(or email..):any way to do it?). There are not enough caracter avalaible to post in comment

Comment: @ken2k: added as new post.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9364154/listview-elements-not-shown-c-sharp-continuation

Comment: solved,simply building another listview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you have forget to set property *View* to *View.Details*.